# Exclude multiple values in if clause

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 30 sites and I need to echo something on 24 of them. How can I exclude the others? This code doesn't work cause i think it's logic is faux:)

```
$currentsite = get_bloginfo('wpurl'); // Here i get the curent site.
```

If the current site matches any of the 6 below, the if clause should not run.

```
if ( $currentsite != 'site 1' || 

$currentsite != 'site1' || 

$currentsite != 'site2'|| 

$currentsite != 'site3' || 

$currentsite != 'site4' ||

$currentsite != 'site5' ) {

do something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your url-s in an array of strings:

```
$linksArray = array();
$linksArray[] = 'site1';
$linksArray[] = 'site2';
$linksArray[] = 'site3';
$linksArray[] = 'site4';
$linksArray[] = 'site5';
$linksArray[] = 'site6';
```

and after that you can use the in_array() function like this:

```
if (!in_array($currentsite, $linksArray) {
   // echo your something
}
```

So it will echo your text if the current url is not in the array containing the excludable urls.

Comment: I'm a newb, how can i put the urls in an array?:)

Comment: @edem +1. I always do this. But is this the most efficient way? Is there a way to almost avoid this scenario with re-factoring of code?

Comment: Would not it be easier to just do `$linksArray = array('site1', 'site2', ...);`? :)

Comment: @Adam: "Premature optimization..." and so on. Its the most readable, that counts.

Comment: @KingCrunch Oh I gave +1; I always use this solution for my own similar problems. I'd just like to know how to avoid it

Comment: I don't think that using the array('site1', 'site2')... syntax makes any difference. You can even use array_push(). Well if you insert 56456465 elements into your array it may make some difference but not with 6 or even 30 elements. You can win 0.001 ms. :)

Comment: @KingCrunch: What is the deal with "Premature optimization..."?

Comment: @edem: "... is the root of all evil" ;)

Comment: @KringCrunch Yea, I know that...but am I optimizing prematurely, or what? :)

Answer (score 4):

In your example above, you would need to replace the ||s with &&s:

```
if ($current_site != 'site1' && $current_site != 'site2' ...)
```

A simpler approach would be to create an array of the sites you are excluding, and negate an in_array check:

```
$excluded_sites = array ('site1','site2','site3');

if (!in_array($current_site, $excluded_sites)) {
    do something...
}
```

Comment: I personnaly prefer just writing something like
`if (!in_array($var, array('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'))) {`
to contain everything in one line.. btw, you forgot the closing bracket in the condition clause :)

Comment: @ashein--classic; where's syntax highlighting when you need it? =)